# Sending email with Indy 9 with an embedded picture

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

I am trying to add to a program of mine the capability of sending html email via SMTP with Indy 9. If the program only contains text (the text will be in Hebrew so I need to display it right to left, which means that I am using HTML statements), then the email is sent correctly. My problem lays with embedding pictures into the HTML stream.

The HTML stream will use a command like

```
<IMG SRC="cid:foo4atfoo1atbar.net" ALT="IETF logo">
```

Whilst the Indy 10 component TIdAttachmentFile has a ComponentID property whose value has to be set to the value that 'cid' references, I can't find where to set the ComponentID property in Indy 9.

At the moment, the code which deals with adding the picture (whose name is in  laPicture.text) looks like this

```
  if laPicture.text <> '' then
  with TIdAttachment.Create (email.MessageParts, laPicture.text) do
   begin
    ContentDisposition:= 'inline';
    ContentType:= 'image/jpeg';
    DisplayName:= ExtractFileName (laPicture.text);
    filename:= ExtractFileName (laPicture.text);
   end;
```

Where do I define the ContentID?

And, although this is a stupid question, how do I know which version of Indy I have?

Comment: For version u can look into c:\RAD Studio\9.0\source\Indy10\Core\IdCompilerDefines.inc

Comment: @Arioch'The: the path to that file on my computer is C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Indy, and inside the file there is no version number. This version is the one distributed with Delphi 7.

Comment: @No'amNewman: Delphi 7 comes with Indy 9 by default.

Comment: Well, at least you can check then ` {$IfDef INDY100}`

Comment: So it looks like I have Indy 9. Does Indy 10 work with Delphi 7?

Comment: it should have been: http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx mentions even D6

See if there is DPKs for D7 at http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx

Or perhaps think about Synapse library instead of Indy, perhaps it can do the work too

Comment: Indy10 works with D7, I used it there for many years until I dropped D7 from my list. I'm not sure if it works on Indy9, but usually you just right click a Indy component and you get the exact Indy version in the context menu that appears within the Forms editor.

Comment: Indy 10 supports Delphi versions going all the way back to D5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIdAttachment` derives from `TIdMessagePart`, which has a public `ContentID` property.  If your installed version of Indy 9 does not have that property, then you are using an outdated version, so use the `ExtraHeaders` property instead to add a `Content-ID` header manually.

Have a look at the following blog article on Indy's website for more information about working with HTML emails:

[HTML Messages](http://www.projectindy.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.EN.aspx)

**Update:** so, if the HTML says `cid:foo4atfoo1atbar.net` then you need to do this in your code to match it:

```
with TIdAttachment.Create (email.MessageParts, laPicture.text) do
begin
  ...
  ContentID := '<foo4atfoo1atbar.net>';
  // or this, if you do not have the ContentID property available:
  // ExtraHeaders.Values['Content-ID'] := '<foo4atfoo1atbar.net>';
end;
```

Note that in Indy 9, you have to provide the brackets manually.  Indy 10 inserts them for you if they are omitted, eg:

```
ContentID := 'foo4atfoo1atbar.net';
```

Comment: I read the quoted article this afternoon; I asked my question because it only shows TIDAttachmentFile.ContentID.

Comment: Read it again, more carefully. `ContentID` is the solution, and the article does say that for Indy 9 as well: "If the attachments are images or sounds that are being used by the HTML, then you also set the **TIdAttachment.ContentID** property to unique values that the HTML can reference via the "cid" protocol. **For example, if the ContentID property of an image attachment is "image1" then the HTML needs to use "cid:image1" as the "src" attribute for any <img> element that displays that image attachment.**"

Comment: I saw at one stage the 'extraheaders' code, but missed the angle brackets. I have now added them and the program sends email with an embedded picture correctly. Thank you.

Comment: i wonder if HTML cn co-exists with UUE in non-multipart message :-)

Comment: No, it cannot. You need to use MIME in order to mix HTML with other data.

Answer (score 0):

I found *a* solution - I didn't need Indy10 not the Content-ID field.

The code which I showed in my question was fine, the problem was probably in the HTML code which displayed the picture. I thought that the "cid" variable had to 'point' to the value of Content-ID; it transpires that it can be set to the name of the file (TIDAttachment.filename), as follows

```
<img src="cid:' + ExtractFileName (laPicture.text) + '"><br>
```

The above line gets inserted into the html stream at the appropriate place.

Comment: The `cid` specified in the HTML needs to match the `Content-ID` header of the attachment, not the filename. That is what `cid` stands for, afterall - cid=ContentID. The only way `cid:filename` could work is if the attachment has a `Content-ID: <filename>` header assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function SendEmail(SMTP: TIdSMTP; CONST AdrTo, AdrFrom, Subject, Body, HtmlImage, DownloadableAttachment: string; SendAsHtml: Boolean= FALSE): Boolean;
VAR MailMessage: TIdMessage;
begin
 Result:= FALSE;
 Assert(SMTP <> NIL, 'SMTP in NIL!');

 MailMessage:= TIdMessage.Create(NIL);
 TRY
  MailMessage.ConvertPreamble:= TRUE;
  MailMessage.Encoding       := meDefault;
  MailMessage.Subject        := Subject;
  MailMessage.From.Address   := AdrFrom;
  MailMessage.Priority       := mpNormal;
  MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := AdrTo;

  {How to send multi-part/attachment emails with Indy:
  www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages
  www.indyproject.org/2008/01/16/new-html-message-builder-class }
  WITH IdMessageBuilder.TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create DO
  TRY
    if SendAsHtml
    then Html.Text := Body
    else PlainText.Text := Body;

    { This will be visible ONLY if the email contains HTML! }
    if SendAsHtml AND FileExists(HtmlImage)
    then HtmlFiles.Add(HtmlImage);

    if FileExists(DownloadableAttachment)
    then Attachments.Add(DownloadableAttachment);
    FillMessage(MailMessage);
  FINALLY
    Free;
  END;

  { Connect }
  TRY
    if NOT SMTP.Connected
    then SMTP.Connect;
  EXCEPT
    on E: Exception DO
     begin
      AppLog.AddError('Cannot connect to the email server.');
      AppLog.AddError(E.Message);
     end;
  END;

  { Send mail }
  if SMTP.Connected then
   TRY
     SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
     Result:= TRUE;
   EXCEPT
     on E:Exception DO
      begin
       AppLog.AddError('Connected to server but could not send email!');
       AppLog.AddError(E.Message);
      end;
   END;

  if SMTP.Connected
  then SMTP.Disconnect;

 FINALLY
  FreeAndNil(MailMessage);
 END;
end;
```

Note: Replace AppLog with your personal logging system or with ShowMessage.

You need of course the libeay32.dll + ssleay32.dll. I would have posted a link to them, but could not find them anymore.