# Sending email with HTML embedded images using Indy SMTP or Clever SMTP, the aplication raises exception

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy10

I'm trying to send email using  Indy SMTP or Clever SMTP components (the result is the same).

The body message is in Html format with embedded image.

When I try to send the message, Delphi raise a critical exception that I can't handle.

The plaform I'm using is Xe10 seattle for windows 32/64 bit applicaion

The error messsage I get is

```
Debugger Fault Notification
xPlan.exe faulted with message:c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
```

The html body format that I'm trying to send is `signature.html`:

```
<HTML>
<BODY style='font-family:"tahoma" style="font-size:8pt" color="#008000";font-style;normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10pt'>
<p><FONT face="Tahoma" style="font-size:8pt">---------------------------------------<BR>
  <BR>
  <IMG src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="167" height="37" ><BR>
  <BR>
  ---------------------------------------<BR>
  </FONT><FONT face="tahoma">Body text </FONT><FONT face="tahoma"><BR>
  Bla Bla Bla
  <BR>
  Italy<BR>
  <BR>
  </FONT><FONT face="courier new">---------------------------------------<BR>
  <BR>
  </FONT><FONT face="tahoma" style="font-size:6pt">Questa e-mail pu&ograve;contenere informazioni confidenziali e/o documenti protetti da copyright. Questa e-mail e destinata all'uso esclusivo del destinatario. Ogni utilizzo non autorizzato &egrave;illegale. Se ha ricevuto questo messaggio di posta elettronica per errore, &egrave;pregato di avvisarci inviando un messaggio di posta elettronica all'indirizzo del mittente, e quindi cancellare e distruggere il messaggio dal Vostro sistema. Vi ringraziamo per la collaborazione</FONT><FONT face="times new roman">.<BR>
  <BR>
  </FONT><FONT face="tahoma">This e-mail may contain confidential information and/or copyright material. This e-mail is intended for the use of the addressee only. Any unauthorized use may be unlawful. If you receive this e-mail by mistake, please advise the sender immediately by using the reply facility in your e-mail software. Thank you for your cooperation.<BR>
  </FONT><FONT face="webdings" style="font-size:24pt" color="#008000">P</FONT><FONT face="tahoma" style="font-size:8pt" color="#008000"> Save a Tree...please don't print this e-mail unless you really need to...Think Before You Print. - Prima di stampare questa mail, valuta se &egrave;realmente necessariotest</FONT></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The code I'm using to send the message is the following:

```
 htmMessage:=TStringList.Create;
 htmMessage.LoadFromFile(GetTempPath+'signature.html');//signature html is the file in the link above


// Clever.Internet.Suite.v.8.1
clMailMessage1.BuildMessage('',htmMessage.text,attachment2,attachment);
clMailMessage1.From.FullAddress := 'myemail@email.com' ;
clMailMessage1.ToList.EmailAddresses := 'destination@mail.com';
clMailMessage1.Subject := 'title test';

clSMTP1.Server := fMAIL_SMTP;
clSMTP1.UserName := fMAIL_UNAME;
clSMTP1.Password := fMAIL_PWD;
clSMTP1.Open();
try
  clSMTP1.Send(clMailMessage1);
finally
  clSMTP1.Close();
end;
```

or

```
 // using Indy
 EmailMessage.Clear;
 EmailMessage.From.Address := 'myemail@email.com';
 EmailMessage.Recipients.Add.Address := 'destination@mail.com';
 EmailMessage.Subject := 'title test';
 with TIdText.Create(EmailMessage.MessageParts, nil) do begin
    Body.Text := htmMessage.text;
 end;
 EmailMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
 SMTP.Host := fMAIL_SMTP;
 SMTP.Username:=fMAIL_UNAME;
 SMTP.Password:=fMAIL_PWD;
 SMTP.Connect;
 SMTP.Send(EmailMessage);
```

Comment: did you see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279211/sending-email-with-indy-9-with-an-embedded-picture

Comment: There is no way to diagnose the problem with the little Information provided. Since both component suites are failing, the likely conclusion is that the AV has nothing to do with the email itself. Maybe the object that owns the email components is being accessed via an invalid object pointer, for instace. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the AV.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried to make the question more clear.
The way to reproduce the trouble is to create a local file as the file I linked above, then try to put the html text in the body of the message.
When you try to send this kind of html text, you can get the Access Violation. The problem is related to the mime64 format because if I try to send a plain text, all works fine. I hope what I wrote is clear.

Comment: You are not making any sense. HTML *is* text, the fact that it contains an embedded image is irrelevant, it is still text, and either component suite will treat it as such.  There is no possible way that the simple presence of the embedded image in the HTML itself can cause this error while sending the email. Something else is going on.

Comment: For that matter, why are you embedding the image in the HTML itself, instead of attaching the image separately to the email and then using a `cid:` reference in the HTML to refer to the attachment?  I wrote a whole blog article on how to create HTML emails with Indy: [HTML Messages](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.aspx), and see also [New HTML Message Builder class](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/RLebeau/20080116.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using an embedded image because this signature file is stored in database. So I have to get the file then send it via email.
If I try to send the same email with the image as attachment, no errors will be raised.

Comment: @GianlucaColombo: using the exact code and HTML that you have shown, no error occurs for me when using the latest Indy. The email is sent and received just fine. However, the HTML is not displayed correctly on the receiving end because you are not assigning anything to the `TIdText.ContentType` property, so it defaults to `'text/plain'`, it should be set to `'text/html'` instead, then the email displays correctly, image and all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right! I found a mistake in my code.
I passed a wrong file instead of what I put in the question.
I Apologize. Probably without your support I could not see my mistake.
Thank you very much